# Seaborn : Can't add hue after upgrading seaborn from 0.9.0 to 0.11.0

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm trying to create a bar plot with hue parameter in `seaborn`. In `seaborn 0.9.0` this syntax works

```
sns.barplot(x=customer['gender'].unique(),y=customer.groupby(['gender'])['gender'].count(),
            data=customer,hue=customer['gender'].unique())
```

But then when I upgraded the `seaborn` into version `0.11.0` somehow the hue creates an error saying  `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).` So I thought removing the `unique()` on the hue will resolve the problem but it turns out it pops out an error saying `ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length`. I need to add the hue. How am I supposed to do it?

Comment: The bars are already colored per 'gender', so `hue=` could be left out.

Comment: but if I don't add hue then there'll be no legend somehow

Comment: A legend ins't very useful when the bars are already labeled on the x-axis. It's confusing and annoying to show the same information twice.